# Incorrect syntax near.. in SQL Server Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why is this giving a "Incorrect syntax near 'master'" error? I put master in square brackets also.

```
CREATE LOGIN SQLDBA with DEFAULT_DATABASE = master
```

Comment: Is that the only line?  What's below it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be because you have not specified the password for the user. try the below

```
CREATE LOGIN SQLDBA with PASSWORD=N'YCm3zAe1qoheDTFiEJDiLDOt/WJ0tdd4//ag6YbL1LE=',DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master]
```

The password will be 1234

Comment: Why do you think the password will be 1234?

Comment: I had a tool script an existing login and it used 'with SID'. I removed the SID part because I was going to run it on a differemt machine. I didn't think about the password. Thanks.

Comment: I mean the Password is 1234 . I took the encrypted password from one of the logins existing in my Local workstation with the password 1234

Comment: If you want the password to be 1234 use `PASSWORD=N'1234'` the password for this login is `YCm3zAe1qoheDTFiEJDiLDOt/WJ0tdd4//ag6YbL1LE=` if you used SSMS to script it out notice `/* For security reasons the login is created disabled and with a random password. */`

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of that because I generated the script of the Login using the script as Function on SSMS. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to create a domain user use the below

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [test_user] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
```

If you are going to create a internal user use the below

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [test_user] WITH PASSWORD=N'Welcome@123' MUST_CHANGE, 
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO
```

`CHECK_EXPIRATION`, `CHECK_POLICY`, `MUST_CHANGE` values are given based on the requirements